# Как балун яндекс карты сделать открытым по умолчанию?

Tags: jquery, html, yandex-maps-api, javascript, css

http://uni.webj.esy.es/

Вывожу метки на яндекс карте. Нужно при загрузке сайта один конкретный балун сделать открытым. Как это сделать?
P.S. На яндекс мап апи нужной информации не нашел.
Код js карты:

```
function init () {
// Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
// заданным id ("map")
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map2', {
    // При инициализации карты, обязательно нужно указать
    // ее центр и коэффициент масштабирования
    center: [56.317222,44.002149],
    zoom: 4
});
//Добавляем элементы управления
myMap.controls.add('smallZoomControl', {
    left: 15,
    top: 15
})
myMap.behaviors.enable('scrollZoom');
myPlacemarkOpera = new ymaps.Placemark([55.851209,37.541246], {
    name: 'Адрес: ООО ЛАНИКС M',
    address: '125438 г. Москва, ул. Лихоборская набережная, д. 18, стр. 1',
    telefon: 'Тел.: +7 (495) 726-57-07, +7 (495) 726-57-10',
    faks: 'Факс: +7 (499) 153-76-31'

}),

    myPlacemarkDramma = new ymaps.Placemark([59.9174455,30.3250575], {
        name: 'Адрес: ООО ЛАНИКС M',
        address: '125438 г. Санкт-Петербург',
        telefon: 'Тел.: +7 (495) 726-57-07, +7 (495) 726-57-10',
        faks: 'Факс: +7 (499) 153-76-31'

    }),

    myPlacemarkKomedia = new ymaps.Placemark([53.8838884,27.594974], {
        name: 'Адрес: ООО ЛАНИКС M',
        address: '125438 г. Минск',
        telefon: 'Тел.: +7 (495) 726-57-07, +7 (495) 726-57-10',
        faks: 'Факс: +7 (499) 153-76-31'

    }),

    // Создаем коллекцию, в которую будем добавлять метки
    myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();

//Добавляем метки в коллекцию геообъектов.
myCollection
    .add(myPlacemarkOpera)
    .add(myPlacemarkDramma)
    .add(myPlacemarkKomedia);

// Создаем шаблон для отображения контента балуна
var myBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div class="sd1"><p>$[properties.name]</p></div>' +
    '<div class="sd2"><p>$[properties.address]</p></div>' +
    '<div class="sd3"><p>$[properties.telefon]</p></div>' +
    '<div class="sd4"><p>$[properties.faks]</p></div>'
);

// Помещаем созданный шаблон в хранилище шаблонов. Теперь наш шаблон доступен по ключу 'my#theaterlayout'.
ymaps.layout.storage.add('my#theaterlayout', myBalloonLayout);

// Задаем наш шаблон для балунов геобъектов коллекции.
myCollection.options.set({
    balloonContentBodyLayout:'my#theaterlayout',
    // Максимальная ширина балуна в пикселах
    balloonMaxWidth: 380
});

// Добавляем коллекцию геообъектов на карту.
myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/map-docpage/#balloon_and_hint) по API

```
MyPlacemark.balloon.open()
```